# How to store unique_ptr in a queue

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have such a code, where I try to store a `std::unique_ptr<T>` in a `std::queue` but it won't compile

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    std::string _s;
public:
    Foo(const std::string &s)
        : _s(s)
    {
        cout << "Foo - ctor";
    }

    ~Foo() {
        cout << "Foo - dtor";
    }

    void Say(const string &s) {
        cout << "I am " << _s << " and addtionaly " << s;
    }
};

typedef std::pair<long, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> MyPairType;
typedef std::deque<MyPairType> MyQueueType;

void Func(const std::unique_ptr<Foo> &pf) {
    pf->Say("Func");
}

void AddToQueue(MyQueueType &q, std::unique_ptr<Foo> &pF){
    MyPairType p;
    ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime((FILETIME*)&p.first);
    p.second = pF; // **Fails here**
    q.push_back(p);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> pF(new Foo("Aliosa"));

    Func(pF);

    return 0;
}
```

It says that I cannot assign in the method AddToQueue. I know this is possible to do with `boost::shared_ptr` but we are trying to get rid of `boost` dependency thus having such issue.

Any idea how to achieve the needed behavior?
thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
p.second = pF;
```

is making a copy of a unique pointer (ie it is no longer unique). You can do the following:

```
MyPairType p;
::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime((FILETIME*)&p.first);
p.second.swap(pF);
q.push_back(p);
```

But remember that then `pF` will no longer reference the pointer address. If you want more references to the same address you need to use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: shared_ptr this is the guy I need to use. Thx!